# How to disable the console output in libsvm (java)

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I am using libsvm in **java** and am experiencing similar issues as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302519/suppressing-the-output-in-libsvm-python) for python.

I am getting a lot of console output during training and prediction and would like to disable it. Sadly, due to a "Service Temporary Unavaiable" I can't access the website, where it might be described ([here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html)). I couldn't find a java related way to disable this warnings (If I did oversee something I apologize)

The Output always looks quite similar to this:

> optimization finished, #iter = 10000000
>   nu = 0.013178458659415372
>   obj = -11.005078334927212, rho = -2.1799731001804696
>   nSV = 20, nBSV = 5
>   Total nSV = 20

Do you know how I can disable this kind of output in java?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To disable output programmatically you need to do the following:

```
svm.svm_set_print_string_function(new libsvm.svm_print_interface(){
    @Override public void print(String s) {} // Disables svm output
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the command line just use the -q option.

```
$ ./svm-train 
Usage: svm-train [options] training_set_file [model_file]
options:
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
   *** lots of stuff cut out...
-q : quiet mode (no outputs)
```

If you have your own java trainer, set the print_func for you svm_print_null.  (I think the only way to do this is to with the svm_train class is by passing "-q" with your other parameters into the main method).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To disable libsvm output in terminal for Java I use:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
      @Override public void write(int b) throws IOException {}
    }));
```

Keep in mind the output to the terminal is disabled, but a logger can be used  instead which does output:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```

Place the log4j.properties file in your resources folder.

The log4j.properties file may look like the following:

```
#info,debug, error,fatal ...
log4j.rootLogger=debug,stdout

#console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```